# Fetching an access token for youtube api iOS "Error" : "invalid_request"

Tags: ios, api, youtube, google-oauth

I'm trying to get an access token for a youtube app for iOS. Here's the relevant code I have been using from my viewDidLoad method:

```
mAuth = [[GTMOAuth2Authentication alloc]init];
[mAuth setClientID:@"<MY CLIENT ID>"];
[mAuth setClientSecret:@"<MY CLIENT SECRET>"];
[mAuth setRedirectURI:@"urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"];
[mAuth setScope:@"https://gdata.youtube.com"];
[self.web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&response_type=code&access_type=offline", mAuth.clientID, mAuth.redirectURI, mAuth.scope]]]];
```

After this is called, the user has to grant access to their account, then I retrieve the auth code from the resulting page in the following code:

```
NSString *string = [self.web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
if([string rangeOfString:@"Success"].location != NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"This is the code page");
    NSString *importantCode = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"%@", importantCode);
    if([self.defaults objectForKey:@"super important code"] == nil){
        [self.defaults setObject:importantCode forKey:@"super important code"];
        [self.defaults synchronize];
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=code", [self.defaults objectForKey:@"super important code"], mAuth.clientID, mAuth.clientSecret, mAuth.redirectURI];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        [self.web loadRequest:request];
    }
    [timer invalidate];
}
```

After that, I should be given the access token in response to my POST request, but instead I get a page that simply says:

```
{
"error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

Does anyone (see where I went wrong)/(know how to retrieve the access token)?

Answer (score 0):

I’d be interested in knowing what the HTTP status code is... I suspect ”invalid_request” means 400, which almost always means there’s some irritating stupid little error in the way you composed your authent URI.  I don’t know enough iOS/ObcJ to tell if you’ve properly URLescaped any funny characters in any of the parameter values, but it’s worth checking.  Or a typo in one of the values, or an extra newline creeping in or something?

Comment: Well, my URI, Client ID, Client Secret and auth code are all copied/parsed from google directly, so I don't think it can be a typo in one of the values. Google did provide me with two URIs, but I barely know anything about web transactions, and I couldn't tell if localhost was just a placeholder name or not. That isn't relevant anyway because when I change the value of the URI the previous steps don't work. However, yes, invalid_request appears to be 400.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as this, I had set the grant_type parameter to 'code' when it should have been 'authorisation_code' if you are reading this and you are using the youtube api, don't make the same mistake. If you're reading this and you're sending a POST request in general, this error "invalid_request" means that either you skipped one of the parameters you should have added, or you added it incorrectly.